# Why do I get an error message when I install pybigwig?

Tags: installation, bioinformatics, genetic-programming

I have a problem that I have tried to solve but I have not found how to do it, when I try to install pyBigWig to be able to read .bb files with

```
pip install pyBigWig
```

I get the following error and I can't use it. Could someone help me?

````
Installing build dependencies ... done Getting requirements to build wheel ... error error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> [18 lines of output] Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in main() File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in main json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs']) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel return hook(config_settings) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jox3ktvi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel']) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jox3ktvi\overlay\Lib\site-pack exec(code, locals()) File "", line 19, in AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.```

 1. 


----------
I tried to download the PyPl archive as pyBigWig-0.3.22.tar.gz locally. I have also tried to link to the github repository where it is but I get the same error every time.

---------
````

Comment: Windows and bioinformatics don't olay together well. Use Unix, for example WSL2 Linux. https://github.com/deeptools/pyBigWig/issues/98